# Java Read/Write a double array to save when program terminates

Tags: java, arrays, file

It's partially a duplicate but i haven't been able to figure any other ones out.
If I have an array

```
static double saving[]= new double[10000];
Arrays.fill(saving, 5000);
```

what would be the best way to save it to a file after I finish manipulating the data so when I use the program again I can use the data I left off with and remove the Arrays.fill

(Thank-you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DataOutputStream and write doubles to it. For example:

```
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("your/file/name"));
for(int i = 0; i < saving.length; ++i)
{
    output.writeDouble(saving[i]);
}
```

Then when loading your program, use the exact opposite:

```
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("your/file/name"));
for(int i = 0; i < saving.length; ++i)
{
    saving[i] = input.readDouble();
}
```

Don't forget to handle the IOExceptions that might occur, and close the streams once you're done with them.